# getters/setters - unable to assign a value from test

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

Given the test code below the property originalOrderAmount is null but it has to be 100. What am I doing wrong?

**Controller:**

```
@TestVisible
    public Decimal originalOrderAmount {
        private set {
        }
        get {
            if (originalOrderAmount == null && !Test.isRunningTest()) {
                originalOrderAmount = Decimal.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('OrderAmount'));
            }

            return originalOrderAmount;
        }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
 static testMethod void testCreditNoteProject(){
   CreditNoteController cnc = new CreditNoteController();
   cnc.originalOrderAmount = 100;
   System.debug(cnc.originalOrderAmount); // originalOrderAmount = null
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setter is not correct and you didn't code for assignment. Thats why value is not getting assigned. Following is the corrected code:

```
@TestVisible
    public Decimal originalOrderAmount {
        private set {
            originalOrderAmount = value;
        }
        get {
            if (originalOrderAmount == null && !Test.isRunningTest()) {
                originalOrderAmount = Decimal.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('OrderAmount'));
            }

            return originalOrderAmount;
        }
}
```

Test class

```
static testMethod void testCreditNoteProject(){
    CreditNoteController cnc = new CreditNoteController();
    cnc.originalOrderAmount = 100;
    System.assertEquals(Decimal.valueOf('100'), cnc.originalOrderAmount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When defining Setters and getters if you use the code block form you have to provide the body of the setter:

```
@TestVisible
public Decimal originalOrderAmount {
    private set {
        originalOrderAmount = value;
    }
    get {
        if (originalOrderAmount == null && !Test.isRunningTest()) {
            originalOrderAmount = Decimal.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('OrderAmount'));
        }

        return originalOrderAmount;
    }
}
```

If you just want it to set the value with no additional logic, simply remove the block `{}` and use the shorthand and the default setter will be used

```
@TestVisible
public Decimal originalOrderAmount {
    private set;
    get {
        if (originalOrderAmount == null && !Test.isRunningTest()) {
            originalOrderAmount = Decimal.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('OrderAmount'));
        }

        return originalOrderAmount;
    }
}
```

Both are valid, the first is just superfluous.

and you test would be almost the same

```
static testMethod void testCreditNoteProject(){
    CreditNoteController cnc = new CreditNoteController();
    cnc.originalOrderAmount = 100;
    System.assertEquals(100, cnc.originalOrderAmount); //You could also use 100.00 but 100 is equal to 100.00 so it really does not matter.
}
```